# visual studio Web Service Request 415 error

Tags: c#, web-services, testing, soap

I am trying to [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182557.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to my project:

I set header: `SOAPAction` as `http://somuri.com/IHubService/processAirLFSearch`

and my body looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://someuri.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ>
        ...
      </OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

finally my url to service is: `http://localhost:24030/HubService.svc`

But I constantly this error:

> HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type
>   'application/octet-stream' was not the expected type 'text/xml;
>   charset=utf-8'.

What am I doing wrong?

By the way here what looks like my project screen shot: 
[image]

Comment: Show request captured by Fiddler or other tool.

Comment: @BWA yep, let me do it

Comment: Same question also covered in [33485373](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485373/vs-web-load-test-returning-415-unsupported-media-type-though-content-type-is-spe)

Answer (score 1):

What captured in fiddler:
This is successful request header

```
POST http://mycomputer:8989/MyService.svc HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://someuri.com/Login"
Content-Length: 389
Host: mycomputer:8989
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

and this is **unsuccessful** request header

```
POST http://mycomputer:8989/MyService.svc HTTP/1.1
SOAPAction: http://someuir.com/Login
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: GZIP
Host: mcomputer:8989
Content-Length: 1604
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

So it is missing

> Content-Type:   text/xml;charset=UTF-8

So in visual studio in web performance test setting Content-type on String body solves problem

[image]

Comment: Quicker to follow [33485373](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485373/vs-web-load-test-returning-415-unsupported-media-type-though-content-type-is-spe)